# Does a solution to an IVP have to be continuous?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Say we had an IVP where $f(t,x)$ is a continuous function.
\begin{align*}
    x' &= f(t,x) \tag{1}\\
    x(t_0) &= x_0,
\end{align*}
where an integral equation is defined as a solution on interval $I$ with $t_0 \in I$ as
\begin{align*}
    x(t) &= x_0 + \int_{t_0}^t f(s,x(s))ds \tag{2}
\end{align*}
where $x(t)$ is a solution to the integral equation.

I wouldn't think eqn (2) would need a solution to be continuous as integrals don't need to be continuous to be integrated. But what about for eqn (1)? I am a little confused on this as it wasn't clear in lecture. Where would it need to be continuous?

Comment: The ODE is just stated as it is; however, when seeking solutions, then a form of continuity (classically) is imposed. For instance if you desire a unique solution, requiring continuity in the first variable and Lipschitz continuity in the second variable (in a certain interval) does it—Picard-Lindelöf Theorem; if only a solution, then the Lipschitz continuity can be relaxed to continuity—a theorem of (I think) Peano. It is, however, possible to have $f$ not continuous and for the ODE to have a solution.

Comment: Yes if $f$ is bounded. You can see from (2) that if $f$ is bounded then $x$ is Lipschitz. Hence, continuous. But it depends on how you interpret the equation. If $x$ is not continuous then (1) does not make sense in the classical sense.